# Disable instant validation in orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to disable instant validation in orbeon form? I want to validate all inputs only when the user submit the form.  But in my current orbeon form, the fields always validate their inputs on focus out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: yes, see [Validation mode](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/form-runner-detail-page#validation-mode).

Comment: Oh great!  That is what I want.  Thank you.